# Laravel - extending Eloquent where clauses depending on dynamic parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I would like to construct a series of eloquent WHERE clauses dependent on the search parameters I collect from a json object.

Something like this (never mind the syntax of object,,, it is an interpretation only to demonstrate):

```
$searchmap = "
{
    "color": "red",
    "height": "1",
    "width": "2",
    "weight": "",
    "size": "",
}";
```

I then take the object and decode to get a search array...

```
$search = json_decode($searchmap, true);
```

If my weight and size are set to null or are an 'empty string' I would have eloquent code that looks like this..

```
$gadgets = Gadget::where('color',   '=', $search['color'])
                 ->where('height',  '=', $search['height'])
                 ->where('width',   '=', $search['width'])
                 ->paginate(9);
```

If they have a value then eloquent code would look like this..

```
$gadgets = Gadget::where('color',   '=', $search['color'])
                 ->where('height',  '=', $search['height'])
                 ->where('width',   '=', $search['width'])
                 ->where('weight',  '=', $search['weight'])
                 ->where('size',    '=', $search['size'])
                 ->paginate(9);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this dynamically.

I suppose the question should be ins there a way to chain eloquent where clauses dynamically based on a given parameter?

In a pseudo context I am looking to do something like this

```
$gadgets = Gadget::

    foreach ($search as $key => $parameter) {
        if ( $parameter <> '' ) {
            ->where($key, '=', $parameter)
        }
    }

->paginate(9);
```

Can chaining of where clauses be created in some way similar to this?

Thank you for taking the time to look at this!

---

**UPDATE:**

I also came up with something like this that seems to work well but i would like to welcome suggestions if improvement is a good idea.

```
$gadgets = New Gadget();
    foreach ($search as $key => $parameter) {
        if($parameter != ''){
            $gadgets = $gadgets->where($key, '=', $parameter);
        }
    }
$gadgets = $gadgets->paginate(9);
```

---

**FINAL**

And thanks to @lukasgeiter below I think I will go with this

```
$gadgets = Gadget::whereNested(function($query) use ($search) {
    foreach ($search as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value != ''){
                $query->where($key, '=', $value);
            }
        }
}, 'and');
$gadgets = $gadgets->paginate(9);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's easy. Laravel's `where` function allows you to pass in an array of key value pairs.

```
$searchmap = array(
    'color' => 'red',
    'height' => '1'
    // etc
);

$gadgets = Gadget::where($searchmap)->paginate(9);
```

If you are curious, that's the relevant part of the source (`\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`)

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    // If the column is an array, we will assume it is an array of key-value pairs
    // and can add them each as a where clause. We will maintain the boolean we
    // received when the method was called and pass it into the nested where.
    if (is_array($column))
    {
        return $this->whereNested(function($query) use ($column)
        {
            foreach ($column as $key => $value)
            {
                $query->where($key, '=', $value);
            }
        }, $boolean);
    }

    // many more lines of code....
}
```

### **Edit**

To have more control over it (e.g. changing the "=" to another comparison operator) try using the code laravel uses internally directly:

```
$gadgets = Gadget::whereNested(function($query) use ($searchmap)
        {
            foreach ($searchmap as $key => $value)
            {
                if($value != ''){
                    $query->where($key, '=', $value);
                }
            }
        }, 'and')->paginate(9);
```

Comment: I am aware of that.. but that is not the point of my question. I MUST dynamically chain where clauses depending on the values in the search array ,, after I have checked array for a variety of conditions. The example here is much simpler than the actual application code. The question is how can I chain the where clauses dynamically.

Comment: I have been passing array of key value pairs to eloquent frequently,, this case however is more complex,, I can't presume that all key value pairs are as simple as "key = x" so I have to create search clauses on the fly depending on examining the details within the search key value pair. Like,,, key could be > x or I could have a need to use other comparison parameters,,,

Comment: I came up with something like this $gadgets = New Gadget(); foreach ($search as $key => $parameter){$gadgets = $gadgets->where($key, '=',$parameter);} $gadgets = $profiles->paginate(9); .. Your answer was actually quite helpful in getting here. Thanks. If you want to make any suggestions around my result they are welcome

Comment: Ye I thought of something like that too, but the nested where seemed more elegant. Have you tried it? (just found a mistake and correct it btw)

Comment: Yes,, I just tested,, ( $parameter should be $value ) it looks good and I like it this way more as well. Does seem more elegant. Also there is still needed a ->get() or in my case ->paginate(9) at the end. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You got me... Copy paste is the worst ;)
Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs it, here's a modified version of lukasgeiter's answer that solves the 'variable number of wheres' problem while also allowing (1) different operators for each `where` clause and (2) the capacity to also use `whereIn` for when one of your "wheres" must be able to match one of multiple values (the function below detects when an array of values is passed and, thus, uses `whereIn` instead of `where`).

The `$paramSets` variable assignment at the beginning (below) essentially describes how to use it.

```
$paramSets = [
        "size"=>["op"=>"=","values"=>"large"],
        "production_date"=>["op"=>">=","values"=>"2015-12-31"],
        "color"=>["op"=>"=","values"=>["red","blue"]],
        "name"=>["op"=>"like","values"=>"M%"]
        ];

    $items = db::table('products')
        ->whereNested(function($query) use ($paramSets) {
            foreach ($paramSets as $k => $v)
            {
                if ($v != ''){
                    if (is_array($v["values"])){
                        $query->whereIn($k,$v["values"]);
                    }
                    else {
                        $query->where($k, $v["op"], $v["values"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 'and');

    dd($items->get());
```