# Dynamic where parameters laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Hello I am trying to build a dynamic where parameters that are from an object. Basically I am using my `$key` as the column name and its `$value` as the value for the column. I think the keys are accurate to the column because I have set it myself before passing it in php. Here is my php code.

```
//model of the request Array [Object] - contains the filter list along with their key
      $filtered_table = Method::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'methods.created_by')
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'methods.type_id');

      foreach ($request->filters as $key => $value) {
        $filtered_table->where($key, '=', $value);
      }//dynamic where parameters

      $filtered_table->get([ 'users.username', 'users.id AS users_id', 'methods.*', 'methods.id AS method_id', 'methods.name AS method_name', 'roles.id AS role_id', 'roles.name AS role_name',
      'types.id AS type_id_typetable', 'types.name AS type_name']);
```

What I am trying to do here is do multiple `->where` clauses so that I can iterate through the object. But I am not sure about the syntax of my code.

Here is similar behavior in javascript that I have made where I make use of the $key and $value separately.

```
 for (var i=0; i < filtered_table.length; i++){
            for (var key in filtered_table[i]){
              console.log(key + " -> " + filtered_table[i][key]);
            }
  }
```

**Could you help me do a similar behavior like that in php then use it to have a dynamic `->where` parameters?**

**EDIT**

I have encountered a problem, see my screenshot.

[image]

```
 public function filterDataCal(Request $request) {
      //model of the request Array [Object] - contains the filter list along with their key
      $filtered_table = Method::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'methods.created_by')
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'methods.type_id')
      ->where(function ($filtered_table) use ($request->filters) {//this is line 122
                   foreach ($request->filters as $key => $value) {
                         $filtered_table->where($key, '=', $value);
                   }
              })
      ->get([ 'users.username', 'users.id AS users_id', 'methods.*', 'methods.id AS method_id', 'methods.name AS method_name', 'roles.id AS role_id', 'roles.name AS role_name',
      'types.id AS type_id_typetable', 'types.name AS type_name']);
      if($filtered_table) {
        return $filtered_table;//data model when returned Array [Object, Object, .....]
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    }
```

BTW, can the results still be returned like what I did there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I can use my array of objects directly in `where` as a searchmap see here.

```
  $filtered_table = Method::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'methods.created_by')
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'methods.type_id')
      ->where($request->filters)    
      ->get([ 'users.username', 'users.id AS users_id', 'methods.*', 'methods.id AS method_id', 'methods.name AS method_name', 'roles.id AS role_id', 'roles.name AS role_name',
      'types.id AS type_id_typetable', 'types.name AS type_name']);
```

Reference

[Laravel - extending Eloquent where clauses depending on dynamic parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682817/laravel-extending-eloquent-where-clauses-depending-on-dynamic-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `concat` to make combine dynamic where with your base query:

```
$filtered_table = Method::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'methods.created_by')
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'methods.type_id');

      foreach ($request->filters as $key => $value) {
        $filtered_table .= $filtered_table->where($key, '=', $value);
      }//dynamic where parameters use `concat` to make the query

      $filtered_table->get([ 'users.username', 'users.id AS users_id', 'methods.*', 'methods.id AS method_id', 'methods.name AS method_name', 'roles.id AS role_id', 'roles.name AS role_name',
      'types.id AS type_id_typetable', 'types.name AS type_name']);
```