# Laravel - Select only specified columns in joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here's my situation I have joined tables but the problem is some of those columns have the same name from other tables. What I want to know is how I can prevent this from happening. The columns that have the same name are `created_at` but I only want to use methods' table created_at (`methods.created_at`). Here is my code to explain my situation better

```
 $filtered_table = Method::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'methods.created_by')
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'methods.type_id')
      ->where($request->filters)//will act as a searchmap
      ->get([ 'users.username', 'users.id AS users_id', 'methods.*', 'methods.id AS method_id', 'methods.name AS method_name', 'roles.id AS role_id', 'roles.name AS role_name',
      'types.id AS type_id_typetable', 'types.name AS type_name']);
```

notice how `->where` is an array of objects, I am using it as a searchmap for the clause. But my problem is like what I said above that the tables has the same name on some columns like for example created_at, the other columns doesn't matter since I am not using it.

**The question is how do I explicitly tell the query that I am using the `methods.created_at` when I am searching it through the searchmap (In this case, `$request->filters['created_at']`.** Please, let me know if you need any more details.

**EDIT**

```
if($("#date_select_off").val() == "daily") {
        let day = $("#day_date").val();
        filter_list.created_at = day;
      }
```

in this code in jquery I am naming the key the same as the column so that I can use it as parameter in the php query. But my like my initial problem I simply can't name it `filter_list.methods.created_at` any help with this is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 2**

[image]

How would I use a 'LIKE' query to that particular key value pair?

```
->where($request->filters)//will act as a searchmap
      ->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', $request->filters['methods.created_at'])
```

I tried doing this but it is just wrong since the key value pair is already hitting on the first where clause.

**EDIT 3**
It could use some improvements but yeah

```
  $filtered_table = Method::leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'methods.created_by')
      ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'users.role_id')
      ->leftJoin('types', 'types.id', '=', 'methods.type_id')
      ->where($request->filters)//will act as a searchmap
      ->orWhere('methods.created_at', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->filters['methods.created_at'] . '%')
      ->get([ 'users.username', 'users.id AS users_id', 'methods.id AS method_id', 'methods.name AS method_name', 'methods.created_at AS method_created_at', 'roles.id AS role_id', 'roles.name AS role_name',
      'types.id AS type_id_typetable', 'types.name AS type_name']);
```

Comment: How are you passing the filters to the query? Search form? If so how does it look like.

Comment: I used the accepted answer in this link, I didn't think it was possible but yeah. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682817/laravel-extending-eloquent-where-clauses-depending-on-dynamic-parameters the filters is array of object with key value pair.

Comment: Something like `$filters = [ "methods.created_at" => "somedate" ];` will work. However you may find yourself struggling to get the request to accept such a thing because laravel's dot notation in arrays means sub-arrays so you should probably first use [`array_dot($request->all())`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-dot).

Comment: ah I see what you mean however now that you mention it I am actually getting the filter from jquery. and I am using its key as a parameter for the columns. see my updated post above

Comment: There's no reason why `filter_list["methods.created_at"]` would not work in JavaScript. Try that and see what you get in your `$request`

Comment: Thank for your help. Check my final post on the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model class as per your requirements to specify what columns you want selected:

```
public function someModel() {
  return $this->belongs_to('otherModel')->select(array('id', 'name'));
}
```

Comment: where should I put this, the controller to where I am querying or the model i am joining it.

Comment: in model class, create method for retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

In this case pass the fully qualified column name in where clause like:

```
->where('methods.created_at', '=', $request->filters)
```

or create a table alias and use the alias like:

```
SELECT col from methods as t1, 
...
WHERE t1.col = 'some value';
```